# Expand tilde path in YAML file

Tags: yaml

I am trying to use `~/Development/Project` in a YAML file but it doesn't get expanded to `/Users/revolt/Development/Project`:

```
repos:
-   repo: ~/Development/Project
```

can it somehow access the bash's `$HOME` variable?

Comment: YAML does not know anything about environment variables. It's a serialization language. You can compare it to JSON. If you are using this in something like ansible, you should specify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tinita mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148691/expand-tilde-path-in-yaml-file#comment83275942_48148691), `YAML` is just a serialization language, so it's not possible.

Functionality like this must be implemented in the software that uses the respective file.